# Spring Boot - Any other ways of customizing SpringApplication class programmatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to add an implementation of the Banner interface without requiring developers to customize the SpringApplication in every application.  Is there any other way to get a reference to this class as SpringBoot is starting up that would allow me to inject my own Banner implementation?  I am aware of the banner.txt customization and would like to do more.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps to set your own banner implementation:

**Create a Banner implementation:**

```
class MySpringBootBanner implements Banner {
    @Override
    public void printBanner(Environment environment, Class<?> sourceClass,
            PrintStream printStream) {
        // Implement your banner
    }
}
```

**Extend `SpringApplication`**

```
public class MySpringApplication extends SpringApplication {
    private Banner banner;

    public MySpringApplication(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, Object... sources) {
        super(resourceLoader, sources);
        super.setBanner(new MySpringBootBanner());
    }

    public MySpringApplication(Object... sources) {
        super(sources);
        super.setBanner(new MySpringBootBanner());
    }

    public void setBanner(Banner yourBanner) {
        this.banner = yourBanner;
    }
}
```

**Start the application:** All your applications can use `MySpringApplication` to start the spring boot applications

```
MySpringApplication app = new MySpringApplication(Application.class);
app.run();
```

Comment: I partially agree with your answer.  The problem is that the SpringApplication class has a number of static "run" methods that create an instance of SpringApplication directly (ignoring your subclass).  This is why I was looking for another approach.

Comment: There is no way to override the static behaviour. Since you are looking to customize the behavior of `SpringApplication` you need to create an instance of the sub-class. The major requirement is to make sure that every spring boot application need not customize. This approach makes sure that the customization is in one class and rest of applications can use this class.